# Why is "will" used here instead of "would"?

Tags: tenses

> With luck, in a couple of decades, it will seem embarrassing that anyone had to hold a conference to debate the relevance of competition. (excerpt from The Economist Apr. 12. 2017)

Why is  "will" used here instead of "would"? or may I say "it will seem embarrassing that anyone hold....."?

Comment: Because the writer is speculating about the future ('in a couple of decades', i.e. twenty years from now).

Comment: _In the future_ it **will** seem embarassing that _in the past_ someone **had** to hold the conference. Similarly: “Sam has left without his bag. He will be home tomorrow. Tomorrow I **will** ask him why he **didn’t** bring his bag when he left.” Asking is in the future; bringing the bag is in the past.

Comment: Why do you question  the use of *will* in the sentence? It's perfectly normal English. Maybe you should ask questions on English Language Learners, not here.